# How can I make the following text appear in my python program?

Tags: python, text, python-2.7

I want to display the following text in my program.When ever I paste the following text in python it interprets backslash as escape sequence and mess ups my ascii art..any idea to get this solved geeks.Here is the text I want to appear in my program

```
  _  __     _ _           _         ____            _               _                 
 | |/ /__ _| | | __ _  __| | __ _  |  _ \ __ _  ___| | ____ _  __ _(_)_ __   __ _ ___ 
 | ' // _` | | |/ _` |/ _` |/ _` | | |_) / _` |/ __| |/ / _` |/ _` | | '_ \ / _` / __|
 | . \ (_| | | | (_| | (_| | (_| | |  __/ (_| | (__|   < (_| | (_| | | | | | (_| \__ \
 |_|\_\__,_|_|_|\__,_|\__,_|\__,_| |_|   \__,_|\___|_|\_\__,_|\__, |_|_| |_|\__, |___/
                                                              |___/         |___/
```

Comment: You could also store this in a text file and have your program read it from the file. This makes that part easier for a non-programmer to maintain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use raw strings:

```
myString = r'''_  __     _ _           _         ____            _               _                 
 | |/ /__ _| | | __ _  __| | __ _  |  _ \ __ _  ___| | ____ _  __ _(_)_ __   __ _ ___ 
 | ' // _` | | |/ _` |/ _` |/ _` | | |_) / _` |/ __| |/ / _` |/ _` | | '_ \ / _` / __|
 | . \ (_| | | | (_| | (_| | (_| | |  __/ (_| | (__|   < (_| | (_| | | | | | (_| \__ \
 |_|\_\__,_|_|_|\__,_|\__,_|\__,_| |_|   \__,_|\___|_|\_\__,_|\__, |_|_| |_|\__, |___/
                                                          |___/         |___/'''
# note the r before the string starts
```

[More Info](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

Try testing the difference between `print '\tHello, world!'` and `print r'\tHello, World!'`

Comment: Just read that link and realised it didn't really say much on it - sorry! The r before the beginning of the string literal prevents the backslash character from escaping. 

It's especially useful when your writing regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

use triple quotes, place this text between `"""` `"""`

```
>>> strs="""_  __     _ _           _         ____            _               _                 
 | |/ /__ _| | | __ _  __| | __ _  |  _ \ __ _  ___| | ____ _  __ _(_)_ __   __ _ ___ 
 | ' // _` | | |/ _` |/ _` |/ _` | | |_) / _` |/ __| |/ / _` |/ _` | | '_ \ / _` / __|
 | . \ (_| | | | (_| | (_| | (_| | |  __/ (_| | (__|   < (_| | (_| | | | | | (_| \__ \
 |_|\_\__,_|_|_|\__,_|\__,_|\__,_| |_|   \__,_|\___|_|\_\__,_|\__, |_|_| |_|\__, |___/
                                                              |___/         |___/     """
>>> print(strs)
_  __     _ _           _         ____            _               _                 
 | |/ /__ _| | | __ _  __| | __ _  |  _ \ __ _  ___| | ____ _  __ _(_)_ __   __ _ ___ 
 | ' // _` | | |/ _` |/ _` |/ _` | | |_) / _` |/ __| |/ / _` |/ _` | | '_ \ / _` / __|
 | . \ (_| | | | (_| | (_| | (_| | |  __/ (_| | (__|   < (_| | (_| | | | | | (_| \__  |_|\_\__,_|_|_|\__,_|\__,_|\__,_| |_|   \__,_|\___|_|\_\__,_|\__, |_|_| |_|\__, |___/
                                                              |___/         |___/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ascii_art = r"""_  __     _ _           _         ____            _               _                 
 | |/ /__ _| | | __ _  __| | __ _  |  _ \ __ _  ___| | ____ _  __ _(_)_ __   __ _ ___ 
 | ' // _` | | |/ _` |/ _` |/ _` | | |_) / _` |/ __| |/ / _` |/ _` | | '_ \ / _` / __|
 | . \ (_| | | | (_| | (_| | (_| | |  __/ (_| | (__|   < (_| | (_| | | | | | (_| \__ \
 |_|\_\__,_|_|_|\__,_|\__,_|\__,_| |_|   \__,_|\___|_|\_\__,_|\__, |_|_| |_|\__, |___/
                                                              |___/         |___/     """
print ascii_art
```

Use `r"""text"""` to avoid backslashes escaping EOL's.